# C programming automatic octal interpretation

Tags: c

Code 1:

```
int a = 0987654321;
printf("%d",a);
```

Code 2:

```
int a;
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("%d",a);
```

Here if we input 0987654321, then it prints the same but in the 1st code snippet, it is giving an error that invalid value 9 in octal constant.

Comment: In scanf, `%d` means to read base 10. Use `%i` to treat leading zero as octal specifier. Don't forget to check the return value of scanf

Comment: Note that with `%i`, the input `0987654321` will return `0`, leaving the `9` in the input buffer for interpretation by the next input operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple representations which you can use when writing code with C -

- Hexadecimal `(0x123A)`
- Binary `(0b1011)` -- Is not supported by standard C but is an extension provided by compilers like `gcc`.
- Octal  `(01237)`
- Decimal `(1234)` -- perhaps the most common.

What you are using here is the octal representation (because it starts with a `0`). Meaning each of the digit is base 8. As a result each of the digit after the `0` can only be in the range `[0-7]`. `9` is not a valid octal digit and hence the compiler is complaining.

If you want to actually use the decimal representation you can remove the `0` as -

```
int a = 987654321;
```

In the second example it actually works fine because `scanf` with `%d` always scans as a decimal representation and `9` is a valid decimal digit.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY let me check the standards, just a minute.

Comment: Try `gcc test.c -std=c11 -pedantic`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes, indeed you are [correct](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p1). I will add a note beside Binary in my answer. Thanks

Comment: Note that C++14 adds binary constants to the C++ language.  It also allows you to add grouping to numbers with `'` characters: `0b0010'0011'1101'1010` is a valid binary constant in C++14.  The punctuation makes ad hoc parsing of C++14 or later vastly more complex than it was before the quotes were allowed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can never fully understand the C++(14+) standards! Thanks for this. But since it is about `C++` and the question is tagged `C`, I will keep it out of the answer.

Comment: Absolutely keep the C++ comment out of the answer.  I've not noticed a decision by the C standard committee to follow the C++ lead on this.  I suspect that left to their own devices, an underscore (`_`) would be preferred to a single quote (`'`) in C, if only because it doesn't confuse naïve parsers in the same way, but C++ already has a use for `_` that (I think) precluded its use as a punctuator for numbers.  C and C++ are as close as possible, but no closer.  I'm not sure where this lies on the 'close as possible' vs 'no closer' spectrum.  But the fact it exists in C++ makes it tempting...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler from the user point of view it would be nicer if it lies on the 'close as possible' side, because most of the code today share header files between C and C++ and header files do define integer constants a lot. It would be ugly to enclose every constant definition in a `#ifdef __cplusplus`. Or they wouldn't use the separators at all which kind of defeats the purpose

Comment: I'm conflicted about it. It won't prevent any C code that currently compiles from compiling. However, it could mess up C analysis code (shell scripts and simple C programs) that did not have to parse numbers specially. Note that the constant I showed has 3 single quotes in it. There's a lot of casual C parsing code that'll break. I have a C comment stripper which also handles C++. Between that and raw strings, there's ample opportunity for C++ to be mishandled. I probably do agree with 'as close as possible' and adding the notations (binary and numeric punctuation) to C — with gritted teeth.